# Suppose $0<a<b<c<1$,find the minimum of $ \max(b-a,c-b,1-c)$ if $b \ge 2a$ or $a+b \le 1$.

Tags: inequality, optimization, maxima-minima

Question: Suppose $0<a<b<c<1$, find the minimum of  $\max(b-a,c-b,1-c)$ if   $b \ge 2a$  or  $ a+b \le 1 $.

Here is my try:

Since $ \begin{cases}
 \max(b-a,c-b,1-c) \ge b-a \\
 \max(b-a,c-b,1-c) \ge c-b \\ 
 \max(b-a,c-b,1-c) \ge 1-c \\
 \end{cases} $,we have $ 3 \times \max(b-a,c-b,1-c)\ge 1-a$.
Then, $$\max(b-a,c-b,1-c) \ge \cfrac{1-a}{3} \qquad (*) $$ with equality if and only if $b-a=c-b=1-c$, or, equivalently,$\begin{cases} b=\cfrac{2a+1}{3} \\c=\cfrac{a+2}{3} \end{cases}$.

Since  $b \ge 2a$  or  $ a+b \le 1 $, it follows that $a \le \cfrac{2}{5}$ when the equality in $(*)$ holds.

Hence $\max(b-a,c-b,1-c) \ge \cfrac{1-a}{3} \ge \cfrac{1}{5}$,where the last equality holds iff $a=\cfrac{2}{5},b=\cfrac{3}{5},c=\cfrac{4}{5}$.

Am I right?

Is this solution correct and clear enough? Or, are there points therein where it lacks in accuracy or clarity of logic?